# Position of progressbar

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, progress-bar, tabbed

I have successfully build a tabbed activity app with four tabs all working as expected.  Each of tab load a web page. My problem is that I don't where to place the progressbar code for each tab some users will know that the page is loading. 
Will the progressbar code be in mainactiviry of the code or each activity /fragment ?
I will appreciate all assistance and examples. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far, so that can better understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by following the below code and the important steps.

1. First, create a NetworkUtils class and add the below code inside that class

   ```
    public static NetworkUtils sNetworkUtils;
   ```

   ```
    
       public static NetworkUtils getInstance() {
               if (sNetworkUtils == null) {
                   sNetworkUtils = new NetworkUtils();
               }
               return sNetworkUtils;
           }
   ```

   ```
    
        public Boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
           ConnectivityManager check = (ConnectivityManager) context.
                   getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
           NetworkInfo[] info = check.getAllNetworkInfo();
           for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
               if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                   return true;
               }
           }
           return false;
       }
   ```

   ```
    
       public static ProgressDialog getProgressDialog(Context context) {
           return ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading please wait..", true);
       }
   ```

   Here, what we are doing is! We are creating a global class and declaring the static methods. So, that it can be used anywhere in your entire project, but within the same package.

   - In the above code, we create a boolean method isNetworkAvailable, this method is used to check your network availability before making the API call. This approach is safe and sound to do network operations.
   - Use the below code to call those static methods to display a progress dialogue along with network checking.

     ```
     if (NetworkUtils.getInstance().isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) { 
        mProgressDialog = NetworkUtils.getProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        loginAPI();
     } else { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.no_network_message),
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     if (mProgressDialog != null) mProgressDialog.dismiss();
     }
     ```
   - In the above code snippet, we are using mProgressDialog. So initialize this mProgressDialog globally inside of your each and every fragment or Activity.
   - In the place of loginAPI(), use your API call method.
   - Inside of the API call, whether you are using the Volley or Retrofit. Use this method to disable the progress dialogue on failure or success of API call.

     ```
     if (mProgressDialog != null) mProgressDialog.dismiss();
     ```

     Please let me know, if you have any queries